# java ojdbc DELETE PreparedStatement won't work

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, sql-delete, ojdbc

i'm building a java program that basically manage a oracle xe 11.2g database using ojdbc6 driver.
I wrote succesfully the methods to search and insert rows but the method that use delete statement do nothing at all.

```
private void eliminaDipartimento()
{
    try {
        PreparedStatement myStm =database.getConnessione().prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Dipartimento WHERE Cod_DIP=? ");
        myStm.setString(1, textField_6.getText());
        myStm.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {new ErrorDialog("Impossibile cancellare il dato");}
}
```

database.getconnessione() get connection via oracle data source while ErrorDialog is basically only a dialog that show the error.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you catch an exception - print it - to find out what is wrong with your statement.

Comment: the problem is that no Exception is thrown, nothing appens....

Comment: if i print textfield_6.getText() i have the text i write in the textfield and if the prepared statement is without the ? it work

Comment: @RiccardoArnese ciao, the problem may be related with data type mismatch, isn't it?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Cod_DIP is CHAR(5) so it should work and when i insert or search for raw getText() everything goes fine. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PreparedStatement myStm =database.getConnessione().prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Dipartimento WHERE Cod_DIP=cast(? as char(5))");
```